# Why MapDB is slower than LMDB and RocksDB?

Tags: database, nosql, key-value-store, lmdb, mapdb

I am testing the read performance of MapDB, LMDB and RocksDB. I am inserting 762207 data into these databases and trying to read a value from the databases using JMH(Java Micro Harashment). These are the results

[Benchmark results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHGSD.png)

I want to know why the performance of the mapdb is slower?

Answer (score 0):

It is slow because of its implementation choices and that it doesn't have a large corporation with a huge developer team working on it to improve it

With that said - just use rocksdb - it is more than sufficient for whatever your use case will be